# Implementing recycler view using sugar ORM

Tags: android, orm, sugarorm

i am trying to display data from a textview on an activity onto a recycler view on a fragment. I have an adapter class to implement the adapter methods. however when i click the fragment the app closes and the .count method remains unable to be resolved. the code is attached below;

```
    public class NotesXFragment extends Fragment {




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View noteview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);

        note_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AddNote.class));
            }
        });
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) noteview.findViewById(R.id.note_rv);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
       // notesDbAdapter = new NotesDbAdapter(getActivity(),notes);
     //   recyclerView.setAdapter(notesDbAdapter);

        notecount = Note.count(Note.class);
        if(notecount>=0){
            notes = Note.listAll(Note.class);
             notesDbAdapter = new NotesDbAdapter(getActivity(),notes);
             recyclerView.setAdapter(notesDbAdapter);
        }


        return noteview        }

}
```

Comment: which version of sugar are you using? If you app crashes you should post your stack trace

Comment: what do you mean by " and the .count method remains unable to be resolved."?

Comment: the line notecount = Note.count(Note.class)

Comment: for some reason Note.class appears in red and when i click it just says method count cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you're correctly importing the Note class. Moreover, you can try to get the count using the SugarRecord class, i find it to work better than using the normal classes.

```
notecount = SugarRecord.count(Note.class);
```

Please check if you're using the most recent version of the library.
Additionally, whenever you update your schema, please increment your DB version in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
```

Comment: Does Note extend Sugar Record? Could you update your question with a print of the error?

Comment: Im not yet allow

Comment: Ive attached the error to the end of the question, thanks

Comment: please, which version of sugar are you using?

Comment: version 2. I cant seem to see why i cant get the count method to work on the class

Comment: version 2? The last available version for Sugar ORM is 1.5. Are you using this one? compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'

Comment: Yeah Great thanks changed it from 1.3 to 1.5 qand it worked, but the app fragment crashes. Please can you see any reason why?

Comment: do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Yeah I attached the image link to the stacktrace

Comment: please, check your DB version as per answer :). Increase the DB version

Comment: you should increase it to any number larger than 2.

Comment: no but i reckon the problem is relating to something else, not the database